# HTTP: Angular 2+TS How to use Observables in HTTP

Tags: http, angular

I found an example from angular.io. This example is very similar to my app, with same kind of methods. This example is using Promises, but I'm using Observables. If I use this example as a reference, I have every method working in my app, except the getHero method in the service, and the ngOnInit in the HeroDetailComponent. So I'm wondering if someone can help and convert this method to an observable, because I'm having trouble with the syntax. Here is the codes I need converted to Observable and the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXZjwuWpFVAK0hVWkbcw?p=preview)

```
//HeroService
  getHero(id: number) { // my id is String
    return this.getHeroes()
               .then(heroes => heroes.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0]);
  }


//HeroDetailComponent
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.routeParams.get('id') !== null) {
      let id = +this.routeParams.get('id');
      this.navigated = true;
      this.heroService.getHero(id)
          .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
    } else {
      this.navigated = false;
      this.hero = new Hero();
    }
  }
```

So I want something like this:

```
//HeroService
public getHero(id: string) {      
    return this.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes.filter(hero => heroes.id === id)[0]); //BTW, what does this [0] mean??        
}
```

EDIT: I had to actually retrieve the list directly, it didn't work with return this.heroes as suggested in answers below. Working example:

```
public getById(id: string) {   
    //return this.getHeroes() <---- didn't work
    return this.http.get('someUrl') // WORKS!
    .map(heroes => this.heroes.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0]);           
}
```

Now I'm still having trouble with my ngOnit, and I can't really understand why!

```
ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this.heroService.getById(id)
    //console.log("retrieved id: ",id ) <----- gives correct id!
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero); 
    //console.log("hero: ", this.hero); <----- gives undefined!
}
```

EDIT2, still getting undefined when trying to move to the detail page :( I think you had one bracket to much in your answer, tried to look and get the correct places for the brackets?

```
ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this.heroService.getById(id)
    .subscribe(heroes => {
      // this code is executed when the response from the server arrives
      this.hero = hero 
    });
    // code here is executed before code from the server arrives
    // even though it is written below
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `subscribe()` on an `Observable` a `Subscription` is returned. You can't call `subscribe()` on a subscription.

Instead use just an operator (`map()`) and use `subscribe()` on the call site:

```
public getHero(id: string) {      
    return this.getHeroes()
    .map(heroes => this.heroes.filter(hero => heroes.id === id)[0]);
}

ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

In contrary to `subscribe()`, `map()` also operates on an `Observable` but also returns an `Observable`.

`[0]` means to just take the first item of the filtered heroes.

**update**

```
ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._searchService.getById(id)
    .subscribe(searchCase => {
      // this code is executed when the response from the server arrives
      this.searchCase = searchCase; 
      console.log("id: ", this.searchCase); 
    });
    // code here is executed before code from the server arrives
    // event though it is written below
}
```

This code is a function

```
    searchCase => {
      // this code is executed when the response from the server arrives
      this.searchCase = searchCase); 
      console.log("id: ", this.searchCase); 
    }
```

that is passed to `subscribe()` and the `Observable` calls this function when it has new data for the subscriber. Therefore this code is not executed immediately but only when the observable emits new data.

Code that comes after `subscribe()` is executed immediately and therefore before above function and therefore `this.searchCase` does not yet have a value.

Comment: THANKS! The getHero works like a charm, but now I have an (wierd?) error in my ngOnInit. Can you help? Updated my question!

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks! I'm new to coding in general, and I remember that I came upon this somewhere, where this is one of the differences between Promises and Observables. But I guess I forgot about it! Updated question again, because the detail page I'm moving to, still complains about it being undefined! I guess you had one bracket too much, or too little, I tried to place the brackets on their right places, but I guess it's still wrong?

Comment: You are right, there was one redundant. Where do you now get the error?  "when trying to move to the detail page " What does that mean?

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to explain myself better. Well, my frame of the app looks almost exactly like the plunker I linked in my question. So just like there I move to a "hero" detailpage. But for me it still gives the hero as undefined when I try to go to the detail page. The console logs in ngOnit in the detail component that the id has been received but I guess the subscription still doesn't work as it should??? Just like the hero example, I e.g try to display the name of the hero.

Comment: I updated the plunker, included my code in as a comment on the hero detail component! In case you see some obvious errors. This should be the only code needed, as the component receives the correct id, so the problem has to be somewhere in there. Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me!

Comment: Well, me neither. I've been staring myself blind on this code for hours and hours. I'll be sure to provide the answer when (if!) I figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you can do it:

```
//HeroService
public getHero(id: string) {      
    return this.getHeroes()
        .map(heroes => this.heroes.filter(hero => heroes.id === id)[0]);  
}

//HeroDetailComponent
ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
        .subscribe(hero => {
            // your code here
        });
}
```

The `[0]` is an array accessor. You're selecting the first element on array index 0 with it. You need this, because `Array.filter()` returns a new array with the filtered values, but you only want one hero.